# Saving session data with Javascript, or similar solution

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, back

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a basic back capability. User goes into Girls listing, which shows him a location screen. Selects a location, and the locations are replaced by images of girls from that location using AJAX. User clicks on a particular girl to view her profile. Now the user wants to go back and have a look at a different girl from that profile - he'd have to go through the location selection process yet again.

What I would like to achieve is to save the location screen the user was in using javascript - just simply save the whole contents of the container div, for them to be reinserted into the dom when the back button (the in page back button, not browser) is pressed. Now the way I was thinking of doing it is passing the string onto php, saving the string using php to flashdata, and then when back button is pressed requesting that data.

Anyone got any simpler solution for what I'm trying to achieve? You can go on www.discreetdelights.co.uk to see what im trying to achieve - a word of caution though, loads  of adult content on there.

Comment: you're talking about `flashdata` are you refering to Codeigniter's custom solution?

Comment: Ahh, sorry yes I am, im using codeigniter for this project - but any session data would do. E.g. overwriting the same session data each time.

Comment: Im not worried about how to do it on php end of things, Im just thinking if there is a clever solution to do it on client end / cache it somehow for later retrieval without going into the whole posting stuff to server and checking server for that data each time.

Answer (score 1):

You could save this data in a **cookie**.

[Javascript cookie functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Comment: Ahh thanks, will keep that in mind for future - I've done it using sessions already anyways :).